# How to active button Profile and Posts at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

If I am in 127.0.0.1:8000/posts/ my button is "active" but If I am in 127.0.0.1:8000/profile/ my button "Profile" is active but button "Post" in not active.

How to active button Profile and Posts at the same time?

```
<div class="container" />
<div class="navbar" />
<div class="navbar-inner" />
<a class="brand {%if request.get_full_path == '/'%} active{%endif%} " href="/">Start</a>
<ul class="nav">
   <li {%if request.get_full_path == '/post/'%}class="active"{%endif%}><a href="/post/">{% trans "Post" %}</a></li>
</ul>



<ul class="nav" />
<li {% if active == 1 %}class="active"{%endif%}><a href="/profile/">{% trans "Profile" %}</a>
</li>
<li {% if active == 2 %}class="active"{%endif%}><a href="/posts/">{% trans "Post" %}</a></li>
....
```

If this is active:

`<li {% if active == 1 %}class="active"{%endif%}><a href="/profile/">{% trans "Profile" %}</a>`

THIS:

`<li {%if request.get_full_path == '/post/'%}class="active"{%endif%}><a href="/post/">{% trans "Post" %}</a></li>`

must also be active

Comment: Where does the value of 'active' get set?? and why can't you just use {%if request.get_full_path == '/post/'%} again instead of {% if active == 1 %}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an if statement which gives one of the list items an active css class. The if statement would not make both buttons active because 'active' cannot have 2 different values at the same time. If for some reason both needs to be active the if statement could be removed and the css class active applied to both.